# GetType - VB.NET - Code is causing syntax error

Tags: vb.net

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim TextBox1 As New TextBox
        Dim TextBox2 As New TextBox
        If (GetType(TextBox1).Equals(GetType(TextBox2))) Then ' Error Here
            Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

I know, GetType for an object returns the Type of it. But here GetType(TextBox1) causes an error. I need to re-write this logic:

```
If (GetType(TextBox1).Equals(GetType(TextBox2))) Then ' Error Here
    Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")
End If
```

I wrote like this:

```
If TextBox1.GetType().FullName.Equals(TextBox2.GetType().FullName) Then ' Works fine
    Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")
End If
```

Can you re-write the logic ?

```
If (GetType(TextBox1).Equals(GetType(TextBox2))) Then ' Error Here
    Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")
End If
```

Comment: Do you mean to use the GetType() method, e.g. TextBox1.GetType() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, GetType() operator expects a typename, not an object. To get a type of the object, use its GetType() method. IOW, in your code you can:

```
GetType(TextBox)
```

but can't:

```
GetType(TextBox1) ' Won't compile!
```

and have to:

```
TextBox1.GetType()
```

So, the error is expected, your solution is fine and your failed re-write attempt is an error, as expected.

For more detailed explanation, check:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetType` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tay4kywk.aspx) works on type names, not variable names.

```
If (GetType(TextBox).Equals(GetType(TextBox))) Then
    Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")
End If
```

If you need to get type of a variable, then what you already have will work, although I don't understand why you needed to call `FullName`:

```
If TextBox1.GetType() Is TextBox2.GetType() Then
    Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")
End If
```

Comment: I think, there is no need to write "FullName" as you have mentioned. This code is working as expected:

Answer (score 0):

If You want check are two object same then use :

`If TypeName(TextBox1).Equals(TypeName(TextBox2)) Then Console.WriteLine("They are equal.")`